# How to create an HTTP streaming client

Tags: python, sockets, http, wireshark

I have an HTTP Server which provides data in JSON format. You can find the Wireshark trace in the following link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NcssNGkweflYBFalBPpG2wMfsrQl-T5U/view?usp=sharing

The trace is from a connection from Webbrowser (Google Chrome) to '192.168.250.17:8070' where the JSON server is located. Once you connect to it you get all data in JSON format.
However, I can't make it work from Python HTTP client and checking the Wireshark trace I saw that it seems to be an HTTP streaming connection, since it opens two TCP connections and then sends all the data to the first connection.

[Wireshark trace overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4PBw.jpg)

My goal is to create an HTTP Client to connect to it and store these data accordingly. Do you have any suggestions?